# Hiding NickServ password on irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

On WeeChat, there is a configuration option to hide your NickServ password while entering it (eg. `/msg NickServ identify •••••••`) but on irssi, there seems to be no such option and it shows your password on the screen as plain text while typing it (eg. `/msg NickServ identify password`) and someone looking at your screen can see your password. Is there a way to have similar behavior of hiding your password? (other than having it auto run the command on connecting)